# Kali linux : unable to "make" airdrop-ng / lorcon / pylorcon2

Tags: kali-linux, make, ruby, aircrack-ng

here is what I'm trying to do

```
cd lorcon
./configure --libdir=/usr/lib
make
make install

cd pylorcon2
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
cd ../ruby-lorcon/
ruby extconf.rb
make
make install
```

everytime that I do followed by ruby "make" I have the following message :

```
root@kali:~/lorcon/ruby-lorcon# make
compiling Lorcon2.c
In file included from Lorcon2.c:5:0:
/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward/rubysig.h:14:2: warning: #warning rubysig.h is obsolete [-Wcpp]
 #warning rubysig.h is obsolete
  ^~~~~~~
Lorcon2.c: In function ‘Lorcon_capture_next’:
Lorcon2.c:535:2: error: ‘TRAP_BEG’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  TRAP_BEG;
  ^~~~~~~~
Lorcon2.c:535:2: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
Lorcon2.c:539:2: error: ‘TRAP_END’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  TRAP_END;
  ^~~~~~~~
Makefile:239: recipe for target 'Lorcon2.o' failed
make: *** [Lorcon2.o] Error 1
```

I tried to reinstall Ruby but no luck.

How can I install this successfully?

Answer (score 1):

the new version of airdrop-ng requires to run

```
python setup.py build  
python setup.py install
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem when making airdrop.

For this, I just manually commented out the line 535, 539, and make the file

Lorcon2.c 
    #ifndef RUBY_19
    //      TRAP_BEG;
    #endif
    ret = pcap_dispatch(pd, 1, (pcap_handler) rblorcon_pcap_handler, (u_char *)&job);
    #ifndef RUBY_19
    //      TRAP_END;
    #endif

Answer (score 0):

BTW, airdrop can now be installed without re-building it.

apt-get install aircrack-ng
cd /usr/src/lorcon/ruby-lorcon/aircrack-ng/scripts/airdrop-ng/
./airdrop-ng